# How can I extract a file from a classpath?

Tags: java, ant

I want to add a file to a classpath from a fileset. How can I do this with Ant?

For example, let's say the fileset with id "my.fileset" contains:

```
dir1/subdir1/file1.jar, dir2/subdir2/file2.jar, dir3/subdir3/file3.jar
```

I know the name of the jar: `"file2.jar"`. Now, I want to find the full filename and add it to a classpath (I assume this will require to use a regex like `".*file2.*`)

Comment: Put examples into code block format to make them standout more and help readability

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you trying to dynamically add the file to the classpath, or are you trying to set a classpath in ant? In ant, once you set a property (like a classpath), you cannot change it.

To create a classpath in a normal build.xml do something like this:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
   <pathelement location="${foo.jar}"/>
   <fileset dir="./bin">
     <include name="*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
   <pathelement location="./lib"/>
   <fileset dir="./lib">
     <include name="**/*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
</path>
```

This will add directories, or every jar in a bin folder, or even every jar in the ./lib sub-tree.

Comment: I am trying to set a new classpath in ant.
I need to add a jar to the new classpath. I do not know where this jar is. I only know that jar corresponds to an entry in a fileset.

Comment: How can you add a jar to a classpath if you don't know where the jar exists? Are you saying that it is already in the classpath?